Theme doesn't change in iOS app with flutter
I'm building an framework with light and dark theme support , I am consuming the framework as local plugin inside the flutter project , when I'm trying to change the theme from light to dark the sdk UI doesn't changing , but it works well When I implement the framework direct in ios library.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return const MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: HomePage(),
  themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
  );
 }
}

